# red5 server installer

Tags: red5

I installed Red5 Server and when I run **`http://localhost:5080`** it shows that red5 is installed successfully. But when I try to run installer folder, it gives error as follow:

```
Host: localhost >Trying to connect
Net status: NetConnection.Connect.Rejected
Net status: NetConnection.Connect.Closed
Trying to connect to war location
```

Answer (score 3):

I had installed it on Linux box and was facing the same problem when accessing URL from remote machine browser using IP. the problem was in my firewall settings, it needs two ports basically, Port - 5080 to open on http and Port - 1935. I had opened the port 5080 but 1935. after opening up the later i was able to access it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It worked for me. I didnt knew I have to open 1935 too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

type  `http://your_ip:_port` to your browser
**ip:** your specified while installation of red5 
**port:** your specified port number in installation 
you will see **installer** link, click on, then choose each Demo and click **Install** 
after both installation progress, check your red5 installation directory for installed demos.Also you will be able to launch demos in `http://your_ip:port/demos/` page.
 
**NOTE:** I assume that you started red5 service on pc, otherwise go services.msc and start red5 service before these